# How to avoid Max error retries exceeded in scraping with Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In Python 3 I made a program to scrape the contents of table rows across multiple pages (97893). Each page has a set of tables, so I browse each page and fill a list

The page that starts is this: http://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/PortalComprasDiretasFavorecido.asp?TipoPesquisa=2&Ano=2017&Pagina=1

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def sopa(link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup =  BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
    table = soup.select("table")[1]
    conjunto = table.findAll("tr")
    return conjunto

planilha = []
for i in range(1,97893):
    link = "http://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/PortalComprasDiretasFavorecido.asp?TipoPesquisa=2&Ano=2017&Pagina="
    link = link + str(i)
    conjunto = sopa(link)
    conta = 0
    for linha in conjunto:
        if conta > 0:
            documento = linha.find("td", {"class": "firstChild"}, {"style": "white-space: nowrap;"}).text.strip()
            nome = linha.find("a").text.strip()
            valor = linha.find("td", {"class": "colunaValor"}).text.strip()
            dicionario = {"documento": documento, "nome": nome, "valor": valor}
            planilha.append(dicionario)
        conta = conta + 1
```

But on page 458 this error appeared:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.portaltransparencia.gov.br', port=80): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /PortalComprasDiretasFavorecido.asp?TipoPesquisa=2&Ano=2017&Pagina=458 
(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7feff9ce8f98>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

I believe I was overthrown because I accessed many pages in sequence. Please, does anyone know how I can avoid this?

Comment: Seems like you're hitting the server with too many requests, maybe use random sleep?

Comment: Thank you. I've never used it, I'll look for the documentation

Comment: For example, could I put this command in my iteration of pages? sleep(randint(10,100))

Comment: Yes, but i don't think you have to wait that much - `sleep(randint(10,100))` is 10 - 100 sec. This `sleep(random.uniform(0.2, 2))` should be enough.

Comment: Thank you. Do I need to import just this? from random import randint
from time import sleep

Comment: import random
from time import sleep

Comment: Yes, that's ok.

Comment: Did not work. I'll try sleep(random.uniform(0.2, 10))

Comment: Which request raised the exception this time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163446/discussion-between-reinaldo-chaves-and-t-m-adam).